# How to fix rotation of object to follow client's mouse?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm building a basic game using plain javascript and I am trying to rotate my object to follow my mouse.

I've tried getting the client's mouse X and Y then subtracting the canvas width and height divided by two. Then taking those values and inputing it into `Math.atan2()`. However, I feel the issue may be in my transform and rotate. The code bellow is what I've tried.

```
WIDTH = c.height;
HEIGHT = c.width;
document.onmousemove = function(ve){
            let cX = -c.width / 2;
            let cY = -c.height / 2;
            let x = ve.offsetX;
            let y = ve.offsetY;
            var rX = cX + x - 8;
            var rY = cY + y - 8;
            player.angle = Math.atan2(rX, rY) / Math.PI * 180;
        }
function update(){
                        var now = Date.now();
                        dt = now - lastUpdate;
                        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
                        ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2);
                        ctx.rotate(player.angle + 10);
                        drawCircle(player.x, player.y, 20, 0, 180, "red");
                        tx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
}
setInterval(update, dt/10000);
```

The player spins around my mouse in wide circles with no apparent pattern.
Here's a gif showing what's happening.
https://gyazo.com/006c99879ecf219791d059de14d98b74

Comment: Put border around your `ctx`. Maybe it's bigger than your image?

Comment: what do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to rotate the object to follow the mouse you need to get the angle between the previous position of the mouse and the actual position of the mouse and use this angle to rotate the object. Also the object is drawn with the tip in the origin of the canvas {x:0,y:0} so you'll need to translate the player to the position of the mouse.

I hope this is what you need.

```js
const ctx = c.getContext("2d")
const HEIGHT = c.height = window.innerHeight;
const WIDTH = c.width = window.innerWidth;
let m = {x:0,y:0}
let prev = {x:0,y:0}
let angle = 0;
   
c.addEventListener("mousemove",(evt)=>{
  ctx.clearRect(-WIDTH, -HEIGHT, 2*WIDTH, 2*HEIGHT);
  // the previous position of the mouse
  prev.x = m.x;
  prev.y = m.y;
  //the actual position of the mouse
  m = oMousePos(c, evt);
  // if the mpuse is moving get the angle between the previoue position and the actual position of the mouse
  if(m.x != prev.x && m.y != prev.y){
  angle = Math.atan2(m.y-prev.y, m.x-prev.x)
  }

  ctx.restore();
  ctx.save();
 
  ctx.translate(m.x, m.y);
  ctx.rotate(angle);
  
  drawPlayer();
  
})  
  
function drawPlayer(){
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(0,0);
  ctx.lineTo(-20,-5);
  ctx.lineTo(-20,5);
  ctx.lineTo(0,0);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill() 
} 
  
// a function to detect the mouse position  
function oMousePos(canvas, evt) {
  var ClientRect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
 return { //objeto
 x: Math.round(evt.clientX - ClientRect.left),
 y: Math.round(evt.clientY - ClientRect.top)
}
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

As an observation: in your code you have <del>`Math.atan2(rX, rY)`</del> The first argument has to be y.